# Change the value of a date in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a data frame called df which looks like this:

```
ID      DATE           RAIN
79001   2013-11-28      2.0
79001   2013-11-29      34.0
79001   2013-11-30      3.0
79002   2013-10-09      17.2
79002   2013-10-10      5.0
79002   2013-10-11      12.0
79003   2013-10-14      14.8
79003   2013-10-15      4.8
79003   2013-10-16      0
```

There is a mistake in the data, such as that for ID 79001 the month is wrong, it should be September and not November. How can I fix the date from 2013-11-28 to 2013-09-28 ?.
I tried the following:

```
df[df$DATUM == "2013-11-28"] <- "2013-09-28"
```

This however doesn't seem like a good way and it doesn't work.
I thought about converting the Date to a character and then changing the value, but I don't know if it works and if it works, how to do it

I am thankful for any help

Thank you a lot

Comment: `df[df$DATUM == as.Date("2013-11-28"), "DATUM"] <- as.Date("2013-09-28")`?

Comment: Enter `df2 <- edit(df)` and a spreadsheet will pop up in which you can change the values.

Comment: Thank you a lot, just one little question, what should I do, if I want to only change the Date from ID 79001 ? (let say, in my data frame I have several dates with 2013-11-28 and all of them are correct, just ID 79001 is wrong ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(textConnection('ID      DATE           RAIN
79001   2013-11-28      2.0
79001   2013-11-29      34.0
79001   2013-11-30      3.0
79002   2013-10-09      17.2
79002   2013-10-10      5.0
79002   2013-10-11      12.0
79003   2013-10-14      14.8
79003   2013-10-15      4.8
79003   2013-10-16      0'),header=T)

df$DATE <- as.Date(df$DATE)

df[df$DATE == "2013-11-28",]$DATE <- as.Date("2013-09-28")

df
```

**output;**

```
 ID DATE        RAIN
  <int> <date>     <dbl>
1 79001 2013-09-28   2  
2 79001 2013-11-29  34  
3 79001 2013-11-30   3  
4 79002 2013-10-09  17.2
5 79002 2013-10-10   5  
6 79002 2013-10-11  12  
7 79003 2013-10-14  14.8
8 79003 2013-10-15   4.8
9 79003 2013-10-16   0
```